# pass the value of get_insert_id

Tags: php

Can you please help me here.
I am trying to save the last id inserted, but it keeps on saving 0, which I don't understand why. Sorry noob here :(
Here are my codes

the index

```
<form action="save_member.php" method="POST">
            Enter your username: <input type="text" name="member"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </form>
```

the save_member

```
include 'connect.php';
session_start();
$_SESSION['member_id'] = $_POST[member];
$sql = mysql_query("insert into users (idusers, member) values ('', '$_POST[member]')");
$_SESSION['last_id'] = mysql_insert_id();
header("Location: chat.php");
```

the chat

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    echo "hello" . " " . $_SESSION['member_id'];
    echo "<br/>";
    ?>
    <?php
    include 'connect.php';
    $q = mysql_query("select * from messages order by time_sent desc");
    while ($w = mysql_fetch_array($q)) {
        ?>
        <div id="show_messages" style="">
            <span id="wrap_messages" style="">
                <span id="message" style=""><?php echo $w['message']; ?> </span> :
                <span id="member_id" style=""><?php echo $w['member_id']; ?></span>
            </span>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
    <br/>
    <div style="margin-right: 450px !important; width: 300px; float: right;">
        <form action="sent_chat_message.php" method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" name="member_id"/>
            <input type="text" name="chat"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </form>
    </div>
```

and the sent_chat_message

```
include 'connect.php';
session_start();
$_SESSION['last_id'] = $last_id;
$r = mysql_query("insert into messages (idmessages, message, member_id) values ('', '$_POST[chat]', '.$last_id.')");
header("Location: chat.php")
```

Comment: don't use mysql-* function instead use mysqli or PDO

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the insert query is getting executed successfully?

Coz' thats must be the reason you are getting `0` as the result of the `mysql_insert_id` aster insert query

If idusers is the primary key I will suggest pass the NULL value instead of empty  string

```
$sql = mysql_query("insert into users (idusers, member) values ('', '$_POST[member]')");
```

Your query should be

```
$sql = mysql_query("insert into users (idusers, member) values (NULL, '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[member])."')");
```

Comment: ehm nothing wrong in insert in the table users. The problem is I am trying to pass the value of the mysql_insert_id from the users insert query to paste it to the foreign key in messages table

Comment: ok fine. then make sure that the idusers is the primary key because mysql_insert_id will return the value of the primary key... and if the table does not have any primary key then you will get `0`

Comment: yep I am sure the idusers is the primary key

Answer (score 1):

From [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) :

Retrieves the ID generated for an AUTO_INCREMENT column by the previous query (usually INSERT).

Is your id field set to AUTO_INCREMENT?

Also, use PDO or mysqli. mysql_* is deprecated.

Comment: OK do you have several db queries running? Try passing the link identifier (that mysql_connect() returned) as a parameter to the function. So mysql_insert_id($connection)

Comment: this thread is solved. What I did is put an "isset" in mysql_insert_id. Thanks for those who replied :)

Comment: Cool! I beleive the accepted thing is to add that as an answer and accept it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

this thread is solved.
What I did is

```
if (isset($_SESSION['last_id']))
    $_SESSION['last_id'] = $_SESSION['last_id'];
else
    $_SESSION['last_id'];
```

Answer (score -1):

You might want to add the ID tag just in-case your browser does not support the NAME tag
Try this

```
<form action="save_member.php" method="POST">
            Enter your username: <input type="text" name="member" id="member"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </form>
```

Comment: How would this help at all?, also what browsers don't support the `name` ***attribute***.